# win 8 notebook install x551ca

Tags: installation

I bought a asus x551ca notebook today with windows 8 installed. I upgraded the os to ubuntu. While doing so I made a new partition table. The pc wont boot to grub, it goes straight to bios. Has anyone had this problem? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it will not be an easy way: check [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1219708) and comment on it as appropriate.